# Security risk by setting authorized_key for root user and limiting to one command?

Tags: ssh, root, cmd

Sometimes a process crashes and IT department has to log into the server and do a `sudo systemctl restart apache2`.
The idea was now to create a wepage an another server (of course) where users can press a button. The webserver will ssh into the server via

`ssh root@server systemctl restart apache2`
where in /root/ssh/.authorized_keys is

`command=systemctl restart apache2 from="192.168.1.0/24" ssh-ed25519 KEY_FINGERPRINT comment`

So the only command that can be executed is restarting the webserver.

Do I oversee any security implications? I know an attacker could some kind denial of service via restarting the webserver all the time, but I'll prevent that by other measures.

Another option would be to edit sudoers to allow `sudo systemctl restart apache2` without password and add above line to .authorized_keys of normal user.

Are there any best practices for this task or maybe even a completly other way I haven't seen? Also hope this questions is not duplicate, at least I didn't find a applicable similiar question.

Comment: You could use a watchdog: a service runs every minute and checks a status page, and if Apache is dead it restarts it...

Comment: I was also thinking about that. The problem is more complex. For example this Apache problem only exits for the internal area, which users seldom need, so a watchdog would lead to unnecessary restarts and thus to broken connections for external users. There are also other services where it would be very useful when normal users can recover them without IT department. So some kind of secure mechanism needed where normal users can recover the service without IT department intervention would be great.

Comment: As Thorium stated, the watch dog **CHECKS** first, no unnecessary restarts. The watchdog can check the equivalent of your button on another web page or check users *sudo set_restart_flag* without handing out ssh access. No denial of service with repetitive restarts if the watchdog checks first.

Comment: If you already have users with shell access to that system, the sudo option seems vastly preferable to me. ThoriumBR's suggestion of a watchdog sounds like a better first pass since it would run unattended. Of course, the long term approach should be to figure out what's crashing and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, it is valid to allow root log-ins with a forced command. The `sshd_config` actually has the `PermitRootLogin forced-commands-only` option for this exact purpose.

However, turning users into some kind of “human systemd” and making them restart system services manually is just bizarre. systemd is perfectly capable of doing that automatically: Edit the Apache unit file and add `Restart=on-failure` to `[Service]`.

Besides that, you or whoever is responsible for the server definitely needs to find out why the services keep crashing. This is not normal. And it seems you've already reached the point where you spend more time on workarounds than it would take to actually investigate and fix the problem.

Comment: What security implications are there when not using "forced-commands-only"? I mean this key can only be used with forced commands because of setting in .authorized_keys but there should be root access possible via pubkey in generell.

Comment: I didn't say that you must or should use `forced-commands-only`. This was an example to show that the OpenSSH developers consider it valid to give individual keys access to a single root command -- which should answer your initial question.

Answer (score 1):

I think a more robust solution would be:

- create a non-root user
- give that user sudo privileges for the one command you need.
- Optional: create a script that does the actual sudo call.
- give it an authorized_keys keys file (with or without the command - either to the script or directly to systemctl).

In your sshd_config file, you can also restrict access to that user to only one IP address. Trying to connect from anywhere else would result in "authentication failed" even if the password and/or key are correct.

Another unrelated side note: I see that you are using ed25519 keys. ED25519 is not bad, but it is not FIPS-approved. If you later try to further lock down your system and use FIPS mode (which is a good idea), ed25519 will be disabled. Changing this later would make a transition to FIPS more complex. I recommend ECDSA or good old RSA.